# com.tableausoftware.jdbc.TableauJDBCException: Error reading metadata for prepared query

Tags: hive, tableau-api, hdp

When I use tableau "order jdbc" connect to hdp3.1 hive I get this error, but "extract" is working.

[An error occurred while communicating with the data source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwabt.png)

An error occurred while communicating with the data source.

Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
com.tableausoftware.jdbc.TableauJDBCException: Error reading metadata for prepared query: SELECT *
FROM (
  select * from dim_boxinfo
) Custom_SQL_Query
LIMIT 1 
Method not supported
There was a Java error.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of connecting to a datasource, Tableau will attempt many types of queries in cascading fashion to determine the functionality of the connection. It looks like this is an example of a time where one of those query types is failing, yet is not necessary for the creation of an extract.

[This link](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/Customizing-JDBC-Connections) discusses the customization of JDBC connections, I do not know the settings well enough to specify which might suppress that warning. ([ODBC connection customization](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/odbc_capabilities.htm) has been around for a long time and might offer some clues as to what is possible.)

Comment: i just select * from table